# Sanitizing sqlite statements

Tags: android, sqlite, escaping, sanitization

I have an app that allows users to create databases and play with them.

I would like to allow them to execute arbitrary sql statements on those databases. Essentially, the app will fetch a sql statement with an EditText and throw it at the database.

Should I restrict these statements? If so, how?

What form a rational sanitization should I use?

Comment: That depends on how much you want the user allow to do. What do you mean with "play"?

Comment: Users should be able to go all the way and bust their dbs but not crash the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most dangerous part of SQLite is the [load_extension function](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#load_extension), but it's disabled by default (and on Android, you cannot enable it even if you wanted to).

With the [ATTACH DATABASE statement](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html), it is possible to open any other database file that the process can access (which, on Android, is restricted to files that belong to your own app), or to create new database files.

Otherwise, the worst that can happen is that the database eats too much memory, storage, or CPU.
All of this is protected against by the Android system.

In summary, there's nothing you need to do.

Comment: Didn't think of ATTACH. Thanks. I'll disable it.